# I have been creating a sample calculator using python tkinter and it has not reached my level of satisfactory

Tags: python, tkinter

The problem with this code is that I would like to resize the calculator according to the users preferred size which I was passionate about when using the windows 10 calculator:

[In the windows 10 calculator, its normal size looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ywAw.png)

[When I maximize it, then it would not look distorted and looks perfect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yd23.jpg)

But with the calculator which I have tested , it looks nice the way it was with its original size:

[This would be how it looks like when it has its original size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CW9A.png)

It looks very distorted however when I maximize it which would look bad.

[The picture shows that the entering box follows the user but the numbers and inputs did not follow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es8eQ.png)

I would like to fix the code and was wondering how I could do it.

```
from tkinter import *

me = Tk()
me.geometry("354x460")
me.title("CALCULATOR")
melabel = Label(me, text="CALCULATOR", bg='dark gray', font=("Times", 30, 'bold'))
melabel.pack(side=TOP)
me.config(background='Dark gray')

textin = StringVar()
operator = ""


def clickbut(number):  # lambda:clickbut(1)
    global operator
    operator = operator + str(number)
    textin.set(operator)


def equlbut():
    global operator
    add = str(eval(operator))
    textin.set(add)
    operator = ''


def equlbut():
    global operator
    sub = str(eval(operator))
    textin.set(sub)
    operator = ''


def equlbut():
    global operator
    mul = str(eval(operator))
    textin.set(mul)
    operator = ''


def equlbut():
    global operator
    div = str(eval(operator))
    textin.set(div)
    operator = ''


def clrbut():
    textin.set('')


metext = Entry(me, font=("Courier New", 12, 'bold'), textvar=textin, width=25, bd=5, bg='powder blue')
metext.pack()

but1 = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', command=lambda: clickbut(1), text="1",
              font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
but1.place(x=10, y=100)

but2 = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', command=lambda: clickbut(2), text="2",
              font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
but2.place(x=10, y=170)

but3 = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', command=lambda: clickbut(3), text="3",
              font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
but3.place(x=10, y=240)

but4 = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', command=lambda: clickbut(4), text="4",
              font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
but4.place(x=75, y=100)

but5 = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', command=lambda: clickbut(5), text="5",
              font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
but5.place(x=75, y=170)

but6 = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', command=lambda: clickbut(6), text="6",
              font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
but6.place(x=75, y=240)

but7 = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', command=lambda: clickbut(7), text="7",
              font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
but7.place(x=140, y=100)

but8 = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', command=lambda: clickbut(8), text="8",
              font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
but8.place(x=140, y=170)

but9 = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', command=lambda: clickbut(9), text="9",
              font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
but9.place(x=140, y=240)

but0 = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', command=lambda: clickbut(0), text="0",
              font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
but0.place(x=10, y=310)

butdot = Button(me, padx=47, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', command=lambda: clickbut("."), text=".",
                font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
butdot.place(x=75, y=310)

butpl = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', text="+", command=lambda: clickbut("+"),
               font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
butpl.place(x=205, y=100)

butsub = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', text="-", command=lambda: clickbut("-"),
                font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
butsub.place(x=205, y=170)

butml = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', text="*", command=lambda: clickbut("*"),
               font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
butml.place(x=205, y=240)

butdiv = Button(me, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', text="/", command=lambda: clickbut("/"),
                font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
butdiv.place(x=205, y=310)

butclear = Button(me, padx=14, pady=119, bd=4, bg='white', text="CE", command=clrbut, font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
butclear.place(x=270, y=100)

butequal = Button(me, padx=151, pady=14, bd=4, bg='white', command=equlbut, text="=", font=("Courier New", 16, 'bold'))
butequal.place(x=10, y=380)
me.mainloop()
```

Comment: You may want to use a layout. For this one, I might go with a grid layout. check here for more info about layouts: https://www.delftstack.com/tutorial/tkinter-tutorial/tkinter-geometry-managers/

Comment: This is a good illustration of why `place` is not the best solution. Since your widgets are mostly in a grid, `grid` is the appropriate choice. I suggest you do a bit of research, and experiment with the `grid` geometry manager.